# How to make an PHP array of Multipart Post data?

Tags: php, arrays, api, paypal

I am working on paypal integration. and make a request to provide evidence in disputes action api.I couldn't make an array of request body which is given below:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-27803/provide-evidence \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-F 'input={
    "evidences": [{
      "evidence_type": "PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT",
      "evidence_info": {
      "tracking_info": [{
       "carrier_name": "FEDEX",
       "tracking_number": "122533485"
   }]
},
"notes": "Test"
}
]
};type=application/json' \
-F 'file1=@NewDoc.pdf'
```

In this request after -F flag i could not make an array because new structure of this json. would u like to make php array of this request api body?.

This is an array that i try send in request:

```
[
  'input' => [
  'evidences' => [
      [
          'evidence_type' => 'PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT',
          'evidence_info' => [
              'tracking_info' => [
                  [
                      'carrier_name' => 'FEDEX',
                      'tracking_number' => '122533485'
                  ]
              ]
          ],
         'notes' => 'Test' 
       ],
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Ok so show us the PHP code you currently have, makes it easier for us to spot the issue and provide a relevant answer

Comment: let me edit my question

Comment: @RiggsFolly i edited my question. u can see my request body array.

Comment: and i know its totall wrong becz i did not mention anything for file.its becz i just dont get this json structure.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP code , as you are try to use curl

```
        $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-27803/provide-evidence";
        $data = [
  'input' => [
  'evidences' => [
      [
          'evidence_type' => 'PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT',
          'evidence_info' => [
              'tracking_info' => [
                  [
                      'carrier_name' => 'FEDEX',
                      'tracking_number' => '122533485'
                  ]
              ]
          ],
         'notes' => 'Test' 
       ],
     ]
   ]
 ]

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

It's a basic post request like form submit from html as you need to send.

for more info you can visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php or can google to use curl with php

Comment: I know. Its just the basic example. But i am using one paypal-sdk. So i dont need to make an curl request. i just have to pass the array of this api request body to the specified function in sdk classes.

Comment: if things does not work then i will have to make my own curl request.

Comment: and it gives me this error `{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid request - see details","debug_id":"aa5edc833c835","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/#errors","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY"}],"links":[]}`.
and i know why is this giving error. its becuase i am sending invalid request body as u can see it say in error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after communicating with customer service email, he gave me more reference. But at present, it can only be implemented with curl. I tried using postman python requests php, which is not good. This is my curl code.
Note the @ symbol behind

```
file1=@1.pdf   this  @
```

[image]

Comment: I use the curl at the end but what i get is this  `{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid request - see details","debug_id":"aa5edc833c835","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/#errors","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY"}],"links":[]}`